# Best way to inject a variable column retrieval list into an SQL query (via psycopg2 execution)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sql-injection, psycopg2

I have a query as such:

```
SELECT_DATA = """select *
                 from schema.table tb
                 order by tb.created_time
                 """
```

However, instead of selecting for all the columns in this table, I want to retrieve by a specified column list that I supply via psycopg2 injection in Python. The supplied column list string would look like this:

```
'col1, col2, col3'
```

Simple enough, except I also need to append the table alias "tb" to the beginning of each column name, so it needs to look like:

```
'tb.col1, tb.col2, tb.col3'
```

The resulting query is therefore:

```
SELECT_DATA = """select tb.col1, tb.col2, tb.col3
                 from schema.table tb
                 order by tb.created_time
                 """
```

The most straightforward way I'm thinking in my head would be to parse the given string into a comma-separated list, append "tb." to the beginning of each column name, then parse the list back to a string for injection. But that seems pretty messy and hard to follow, so I was wondering if there might a better way to handle this?

Comment: See this:https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I understand *how* to inject, I'm more asking about a good approach to pre-injection - actually configuring the given string for a proper injection.

Comment: Table aliases are unnecessary if query only has one table.

Comment: Given `col_str = 'col1, col2, col3' ` then `', '.join(['tb.' + fld.strip() for fld in col_str.split(',')])` which yields: `'tb.col1, tb.col2, tb.col3'`. So a one liner to do what you propose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a list comprehension of `sqlIdentifiers` after splitting  comma-separated string:

```py
commas_sep_str = "col1, col2, col3"
field_identifiers = [sql.Identifier(s) for s in commas_sep_str.split(',')]

query = (sql.SQL("select {fields} from {schema}.{table}")
            .format(
                fields=sql.SQL(',').join(field_identifiers),
                schema=sql.Identifier('my_schema')
                table=sql.Identifier('my_table')
             )
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for this - so a simple injection of that comma-separated string wouldn't work because you'd need to create sqlIdentifiers out of each column name while also setting the commas themselves to be SQL-valid?

Comment: In other Python DB-APIs you would simply concatenate the comma separated string into the SQL statement. Since these are identifiers and not literal values that malicious users can [run SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), concatenation of columns and table name is OK. However, `psycopg2` provides extensions to safely escape identifiers with methods like, `sql.Identifier` to prevent [invalid identifiers and names from untrusted sources](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql).